# When did the /θ/ sound die out in the continental Germanic languages?

Tags: historical-linguistics, germanic-languages, dental-fricative

I am looking for dates when the /θ/ phoneme (which once written *ð* and *þ* in English, and now by the *th* grapheme) inherited from Proto-Germanic died out in continental Germanic languages.

In other words, when was the sound shift from /θ to /d/ was completed on the European mainland, so not including Britain and Iceland?

EDIT: BTW, I am interested in dates for each of the major Germanic languages.

Comment: Germanic people settled the British Islands and Iceland in the 5th and 9th centuries AD, respectively  - and both English and Icelandic retained /θ/, so it must have started after the 9th century. But I have no idea of when it finished - other than Luther's translation of the Bible is already exempt of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Swedish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_German_consonant_shift#.2F.CE.B8.2F_.3E_.2Fd.2F_.28phase_4.29) seems to be the last holdout, as attested in the [Gustav Vasa Bible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustav_Vasa_Bible) published 1540-1.